# string.split() vs [...string] in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), I know that `string.split()` provides flexibility to add `seperator` and `limit` as compared to `[...string]`.

**What I'm curious about?**

1. Is there any performance difference?
2. Use cases of both of them.
3. Which is recommended as a best practice?

Comment: You have laid it down already: the `[...string]` does exactly the same as `string.split('')`, but the latter offers many more possibilities.

Comment: Thanks. But any performance difference you know about when string length is in millions?

Comment: Spread performs better for very short strings, otherwise split is better. https://jsbench.me/38ka6egseu/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[...string]` spreads the individual characters of a string into an `Array` of characters, and it's just that. `String.split` on the other hand has more use cases: you can split the string using a regular expression (e.g. `string.split(/\n/)` or a substring (e.g. `string.split('","')`). So best practice should be inspired by the use case I suppose.

I don't know of performance differences, but would assume that performance may only be a problem with very long strings (in both cases).